# SP2013 rollback to another version of a LIST or LIBRARY?

Tags: 2013, library, version

Is there a way to roll back to previous versions of a LIST or LIBRARY, and not Items within it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versioning exists for items or documents but not the lists and libraries themselves. If you have database backups, you could perform a restore but that would restore everything that relies on that content database.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thank you.